# Is it faster to add a key to a dictionary or append a value to a list in Python?

Tags: python, performance, cpu-speed

I have an application where I need to build a list or a dictionary and speed is important. Normally I would just declare a list of zeros of the appropriate length and assign values one at a time but I need to be able to check the length and have it still be meaningful.

Would it be faster to add a key value pair to a dictionary or to append a value to a list? The length of the lists and dictionary will usually be small (less than 100) but this isn't always true and in worst case could be much larger.

I could also just have a variable to keep track of where I am in the list if both of these operations are too slow.

Comment: My guess is that appending to a list will be faster, since you don't need the extra `key` object..., but as with all performance queries you'll have to measure against your data.

Comment: Measure it with the `timeit` module. https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html

Comment: ... Note that `list` operations are designed to be amortized O(1). I.e. by pre-allocating the list you aren't really saving that much time, just a fraction of it. Dicts require hashing, so keep in mind that the more complex the object is the more time it will take to hash, and thus `dict` will become slower and slower, why `list` doesn't care.  Also `dict`s lookup are significantly slower (again: you need to first hash the key).  BTW: you know that `set` is *exactly* just a `dict` with no values? So if you want a hashing solution use `set` and avoid setting fake values.

Answer (score 4):

Best way is to use `time()` to check your execution time.

In following example dict is slightly faster.

```
from time import time

st_time = time()
b = dict()
for i in range(1, 10000000):
    b[i] = i

print (time() - st_time)

st_time = time()
a = []
for i in range(1, 10000000):
    a.append(i)

print (time() - st_time)

1.45600008965
1.52499985695
```

Comment: On my system properly using `timeit` instead of using `time` explicitly `list.append` is slightly faster. Also note that you could do: `a = list(range(1, 1000000))` which significantly reduces the timings.

Comment: why aren't you using the `timeit` module (which is created for exactly these kinds of micro-benchmarks).  Also, your data isn't similar to what the OP describes..

Comment: You should also always test performance code inside a function (I'm guessing global variable lookup has a significant impact on your results).

Comment: in `timeit` I was not able to pass expression

    timeit(b['a']=1, 100000)
    SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression

Comment: I am just trying to give idea., he can apply the logic against his code.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is a [deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque): purpose built for fast `append` and `pop` (especially `popleft`).

> Deques are a generalization of stacks and queues (the name is pronounced “deck” and is short for “double-ended queue”). Deques support thread-safe, memory efficient appends and pops from either side of the deque with approximately the same O(1) performance in either direction.

Caveat: read access is slower than list or dict if you're trying to access items in the middle.

However, I was surprised that for adding new items, dict was at least as fast:

```
python -m timeit -s "from collections import deque; d = deque()" "for i in range(10000000):" " d.append(i)"
1 loop, best of 5: 459 msec per loop

python -m timeit -s "l = list()" "for i in range(10000000):" " l.append(i)"
1 loop, best of 5: 517 msec per loop

python -m timeit -s "d = dict()" "for i in range(10000000):" " d[i] = i"
1 loop, best of 5: 450 msec per loop
```